# How to generate identity tensor with python?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, identity, tensor

I know about `np.eye` which generates identity matrix. I mean the identity matrix as

> In linear algebra, the identity matrix, or sometimes ambiguously called a `unit matrix`, of size n is the `n × n` square matrix with ones on the main diagonal and zeros elsewhere.

And I know that we can create it in `Numpy` with `np.identity(3)`.

> But, I would like to know how can I have an identity Tensor in python.

I would like to use identity tensor in tensors multiplication. Like below:

where `G = Er ×1 U1 ×2 U2 ...×M` `UM` is a transformation tensor, and `Er ∈` 
   `R` `r×r×...×r` is an identity tensor (the diagonal elements are 1, and all other entries are 0). I need to have the code for generating the `identity tensor`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the desired shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def nd_id(n, d):
    out = np.zeros( (n,) * d )
    out[ tuple([np.arange(n)] * d) ] = 1
    return out
```

Testing

```
nd_id(3,3)
Out[]: 
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to know how can I calculate the covariance of Tensors in python?  is it the same with matrixes?

Comment: Ask another question

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `np.identity` use `tf.eye`:

```
tf.eye(2)
# [[1., 0.],
#  [0., 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a function that returns one if all indices are equal, but it must be vectorized in order to be used in np.fromfunction

```
np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(lambda i,j,k: int(i==j==k)), (3,3,3))
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]]])
```